# How to get specific field data with Firestore get request?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I've got Firebase Phone Auth successfully setup on my app.

On my home, when the user is logged in, i retrieve his specific uid to create a firestore document named with his uid to add more informations about the user.
I add a "points" field for each user.

I'm tryng to get that specific "points" field value.

Here's a screen of my Firestore :
[image]

And here's a screen of my code with what's printed to the console : 
[image]

Can someone help and explain me the solution ? I already know that we can't get only a field value with firestore get request but can't find the solution to store "points" value to display it to my user.

Thanks a lot.

If needed, here's my code :

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

func getUID() -> String {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
      return user.uid
    }
    return "Can't fetch user data."
}

struct HomeView: View {

    let uid = getUID()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()


    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("User id = \(uid)")
                .font(.headline)
                .onAppear {
                    self.db.collection("users").document(self.uid).setData([
                        "points" : 2
                    ])
                }

            Button(action: {

                let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(self.uid)

                docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                        let dataDescription = document.data()
                        print(dataDescription)
                    } else {
                        print("Document \(document) does not exist")
                    }
                }

            }) {
                Text("See my points")
            }

            Button(action: {
                try! Auth.auth().signOut()

                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "statusChange"), object: nil)
            }) {
                Text("Logout")
            }
        }

    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways for accessing specific fields in Firestore documents:

1. The `data()` method returns a dictionary mapping `String` to `Any`. You can read attributes like so:

```swift
let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
let author = data["author"] as? String ?? ""
let numberOfPages = data["pages"] as? Int ?? 0
```

2. You can use Firestore's Codable support to map documents to Swift structs / classes with a one-liner, like this:

```swift
let book = try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Book.self)
```

Read more about these [here](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/) and [here](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/), respectively.

I'd recommend extracting any data access code into a view model or a store. The articles I linked to show how to do this. This will make your code easier to read, less error-prone, and more maintainable.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your course [here](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/) but the same book is always displayed in the list. Is it normal ? I followed the tutorial step by step.

Comment: Make sure the `Book` is `Identifiable`, and that each book instance has a unique `id`. In the part of the tutorial you linked to, that is achieved by generating a UUID whenever a book is created. In the follow-up, we use `@DocumentID` to map the Firestore document ID to the book's `id` attribute.

Comment: They have a different id because i created two books directly in Firebase. In order to debug, i copied all your code from the tutorial and the problem is still here. I'll start again !